# MYSQL use the result of previous query

Tags: mysql, sql

Using my database I need to find personnel only between 18 and 25 years old, but prior to that I need to calculate thier age (type date).
I don't know if I should use one query or more to get this result.

I came up with this but it doesn't work.
It says:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'TIMESTAMPDIFF' in  where clause

```
SELECT name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE())
from personnel
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF BETWEEN 18 AND 25 ;
```

Comment: Yes, because `WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF` is doing exactly what you have asked it to do and is looking for a column named `TIMESTAMPDIFF`; you need to repeat the expression, or use it as a derived table.

Comment: In case it's not clear, like `WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 25`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!
The reslut was misleading because in fact there aren't any people in this age interval.
`SELECT name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) from personnel WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 18 AND 25;`